# Is this NP-Complete? If so, knapsack, MIS, set-filling or scheduling?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, knapsack-problem, np-complete

I've got a "gut-feeling" that the problem I'm facing in my application is NP-complete, but I'm after help classifying it.

**The problem**

- We have a bag with n *heterogeneous* slots
- We can either put an item (with an associated value) in each slot, or leave it empty. A slot may contain at most one item.
- Since the slots are heterogeneous, an item for slot #2 cannot go in slot #3
- We have a finite set of slot-filling actions
- Each action may be invoked at most once
- Invoking a given action will fill some (1-n) of the slots with a fixed value (specific to the action), but only if all requested slots are available (otherwise the action cannot be invoked) i.e. all requested slots or none.

**How do we determine the set of actions to invoke to maximise the total value in the bag?**

An example:

- We have 5 slots, numbered #1-#5
- We have three actions, A1, A2 and A3
- A1 wants to put value $30 in slots #1 through #5
- A2 wants to put $50 in slots #1 & #2
- A3 wants to put $50 in slots #4 & #5

The optimal solution for this example is to invoke actions A2 & A3 (for a total value of $200, leaving slot #3 empty) - rather than invoking A1 (which would fill all slots, but only give a total of $150).

**Follow-up question - how should I brute-force this?**

Some thoughts:

- We will want to prune off any action A[y] which covers the *exact* same slots as another action A[x] if the slot value ($) associated with A[y] is less than or equal to that of A[x].
- Other than that, I think evaluating the solution space boils down to iterating through the powerset of all remaining actions
- Of the sets {S1, S2...} in the powerset of all actions, if S2 is a subset of S1 AND all the actions applied successfully for S1 then we can disregard S2 (and all it's subsets!) without evaluating them, since they can never give a better result. In other words, if we can find a set that applies successfully early on, we can disregard all the subsets of it (significantly reducing what we have to test)

Interested to hear of any other optimisations you can think of.

Comment: If it helps, we can assume slots filled by an action must be contiguous -
 we can break down a non-contiguous action into two or more actions which are contiguous.

Comment: I think I understand the rules of this game, but a non-trivial example or two would help tremendously.

Comment: Have added an example, hopefully it is clear!

Comment: So each slot can contain at most one item?

Comment: Yep - a slot can contain at most one item. Have updated the description text.

Comment: I've added a follow-up question - asking for suggestions as to how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NP-completeness is about decision problems, and yours is an optimization problem. If we change it to feasibility ("does a solution ≥ *m* exist?") then we can trivially reduce [set packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing) to your problem, and your problem to 0-1 [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_linear_programming), both of which are known to be NP-complete. Congratulations, you're NP-complete!

I'm not sure which [NPO-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem#NP_optimization_problem) class your problem falls into, though.

Comment: @mcdowella Not quite? The solution might not be a perfect cover.

Comment: OK - not quite. I think that given an exact cover problem you can create a problem of this type which gives the highest possible answer only if the exact cover is completely solveable, but yes the fact that the solution might not be a perfect cover and probably the different values involved means that it is not quite exact cover.